# Xcode and iphone/ipad simualtor w/o iOS sdk

Tags: xcode, macos

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question. But I want to download xcode to use the simulator. Will just downloading xcode come with it? Or will I need the iOS sdk too, which I think requires like $99 for a developer license. I really hope that the simulator comes free with xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pay any fee to download XCode and the simulator.  You'll need to pay the fee if you want to release an app in the app store.

Comment: You have to pay to run your app on hardware, even for debugging and beta testing. Additionally, the simulator is *part* of the Xcode download.

Answer (score 0):

The simulators for the iOS versions in context are included as part of the XCode installer.
In addition, once you have XCode installed, you are able to install additional simulators.
A paid developer account is required to provision your devices, utilize iTunes Connect and submit apps to the app store.